# Drop down list in MVC from DB text, value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, drop-down-menu

I have problem with dropdownlist. I want show text in selectedlist but select Id.
How I implement view? In view I must save selected data to model (odbiorca)

Controller:

```
var odbiorca = dbU.Uczniowie.OrderBy(d => d.Nazwisko).Select(m => m.Nazwisko + " " + m.Imie).ToList(); //return Names
          var odbiorcaId= dbU.Uczniowie.OrderBy(d => d.Id).Select(m => m.Nazwisko + " " + m.Imie).ToList(); //return IDs

          List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            for (int i=0;i<dbU.Uczniowie.Count();i++)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = odbiorca[i], Value = odbiorcaId[i] }); 
            }

ViewBag.odbiorca = items;
```

Model:

```
public class Uwaga
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string odbiorca { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public  DateTime data { get; set; }

    }
```

I tried this solution but the program saves text, but not value. 
@Html.DropDownList("odbiorca", "----")

Comment: how you pass value in DropDownList i dont see the view where the dropdownlist receive ViewBag.odbiorca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your linq statements return the same values.

```
var odbiorca = dbU.Uczniowie.OrderBy(d => d.Nazwisko).Select(m => m.Nazwisko + " " + m.Imie).ToList(); //return Names
var odbiorcaId= dbU.Uczniowie.OrderBy(d => d.Id).Select(m => m.Nazwisko + " " + m.Imie).ToList(); //return IDs
```

both of these return a list of `m.Nazwisko + " " + m.Imie`  there is no Id.

you should just use one query to get your select list

```
var list = dbU.Uczniowie.Select(a => new {Text= a.Nazwisko + " " + a.Imie, Value = a.Id}).ToList();

ViewBag.odbiorca = list.Select(a => new SelectListItem{ Text = a.Text, Value = a.Value.ToString()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Lets take your model class:

```
public class Uwaga
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    Required]
    public string odbiorca { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public  DateTime data { get; set; }
}
```

In the view you can use the same helper: `@Html.DropDownList("odbiorca", "----")`

But, in the controller you set the "id" and "text" columns through a `SelectList` object. Take the example in the default action in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Creates a example list with multiple "Uwaga" items, 
        //but you might want to pull the data from the database
        List<Uwaga> UwagaList = new List<Uwaga>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Uwaga item = new Uwaga();
            item.Id = i;
            item.odbiorca = "odbiorca " + i;
            UwagaList.Add(item);
        }

        //Create a SelectList object, the first parameter is the list created above.
        //The second parameter is the "id" key and the thirth 
        //parameter is the text you want to display in the dropdown.
        var SelectList = new SelectList(UwagaList, "Id", "odbiorca");

        //Fill the dropdownlist "odbiorca" using ViewData.
        ViewData["odbiorca"] = SelectList;
    }
```

I hope it helps.